# RAE: Dios existe pero los seres extraterrestres no. ¿?

Tags: rae, acepciones

¿Alguien tiene una explicación lógica, no subjetiva, a que según la RAE no quepa duda de que Dios exista y sea un ser supremo, mientras que los objetos o seres extraterrestres (podemos estar hablando de bacterias, no necesariamente de organismos más desarrollados) existan sólo "supuestamente"?

Si mañanana cae un meteorito con bacterias fosilizadas y decimos que son bacterias extraterrestes, según la RAE, ¿Sólo lo serán "supuestamente"?

http://dle.rae.es/dios

**dios. =>**

(Del lat. deus).

**1. m. Ser supremo que en las religiones monoteístas es considerado hacedor del universo.**

ORTOGR. Escr. con may. inicial.

2. m. Deidad a que dan o han dado culto las diversas religiones.

http://dle.rae.es/extraterrestre

**extraterrestre. =>**

1. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que pertenece al espacio exterior de la Tierra o procede de él.

**2. adj. Dicho de un objeto o de un ser: Supuestamente venido desde el espacio exterior a la Tierra. U. t. c. s.**

Dicho desde el mayor de los respetos a cualquier creencia: En la existencia de otras formas de vida extraterrestes (insisto en que hablo de bacterias, no voy más lejos), parece lógico creer dado que somos el ejemplo viviente de que es posible que se dé, y la probabilidad apunta a que entre trillones o cuatrillones de planetas similares, alguna otra forma de vida habrá evolucionado.

En cambio de la existencia de ese "ser supremo", no tenemos ninguna prueba (no digo que no exista). Entonces, ¿Qué sentido tiene que la RAE ponga en duda lo segundo y asuma sin lugar a dudas que Dios existe?

**EDIT:** Para evitar entrar a discutir si la RAE asume o no la existencia de Dios, incluyo la definición que da de "espíritu" (que hasta donde yo sé, no hemos demostrado que existan, pero aquí no hay ningún "supuestamente"):

http://dle.rae.es/esp%C3%ADritu

**espíritu. =>**

(Del lat. spirĭtus).

1. m. Ser inmaterial y dotado de razón.
2. m. Alma racional.
3. m. Don sobrenatural y gracia particular **que Dios suele dar a algunas criaturas.** Espíritu de profecía.

Comment: Cuando mañana caiga el meteorito con las bacterias fosilizadas la RAE revisará su definición y quitará el "supuestamente".

Comment: Claro, de la misma forma que quitaron el "supuestamente" de que Dios fuese el ser supremo cuando cayó del cielo, claro.

Comment: No es necesario "suponer" o no la existencia de dios. En https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Dioses puedes encontrar una lista de cientos de dioses. Uno de ellos es sustantivo propio y se escribe con mayúscula (el de la cultura cristiana). Estás confundiendo un concepto con un objeto natural. ¿Don Quijote es un tipo que _supuestamente_ desfacía entuertos? ¿Penélope _supuestamente_ espera en el andén?

Comment: @Rodrigo: "No es necesario "suponer" o no la existencia de dios". Según tu lógica no podemos hablar de bacterias extraterrestres sin añadir el "supuestamente" porque aún no han caído del cielo, pero en cambio no es necesario en el caso de Dios. ¿Qué sentido tiene eso? No me parece un argumento válido.

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que dios es un concepto cultural, como _comercio_, _pariente_, _comunidad_, _gobierno_, _matrimonio_, etc. No es necesaria la experiencia para validar su existencia. Son palabras que se refieren a entidades que existen aunque no te gusten y aunque no crea en ellas. Son parte inherente del mundo que nos tocó. Y aparte, oye, poner la pancarta "Los extraterrestres tienen los mismos derechos de dios" frente al edificio de la RAE es llevar al extremo una odiosa moda muy en boga que no aporta un milímetro al cambio cultural y que, al contrario, se centra en formalidades.

Comment: Vamos a ver, @Rodrigo, ni yo ni la RAE hablamos de dios, sino de Dios. Te empeñas en discutir sobre el concepto de "dios" cuando no es lo que yo estoy preguntando. Sobre la pancarta en defensa de los extraterrestres por mí como si pones que todos ellos al paredón; yo he hablado en todo momento de bacterias como ejemplo, no sé de dónde te sacas el resto de la película.

Comment: Esta pregunta parecía interesante, pero tras leer los comentarios (o las respuestas del OP a los comentarios y respuestas) me parece más una queja o crítica disfrazada de pregunta. @AlbertoMartín, la pregunta era interesante, pero creo que has llevado un poco lejos el "la RAE se equivoca". Tienes mi +1 por la pregunta, pero ese "_No sabía que la RAE se pronunciase tan contundentemente sobre la religión. No deja de saberme mal y parecerme innecesario_" da que pensar que buscabas más la polémica o crítica que una respuesta.

Comment: @Diego, te agradezco la crítica argumentada y por ello te doy una explicación absolutamente sincera y breve: La crítica no estaba difrazada, era evidente, y partía de que desconocía esas declaraciones tan contundentes (para mí lo son). Pero la crítica, así como el "saberme mal", era desde mi idea de que la RAE no tenía postura religiosa definida y que entidades autodefinidas "neutrales" traten de inculcar ideas, del tipo que sean, es algo que no me gusta. Sabiendo ahora que no lo hace "de tapadillo", sino que el error ha sido mío por presuponer que era así, no tengo nada que objetar.

Comment: Me cuesta ver la polémica... Para mí en _[...] en las religiones monoteístas es considerado [...]_ va implícito el «supuestamente». No me parece que la RAE se esté pronunciando.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the motives of the publishers of a dictionary, and has nothing to do with the Spanish language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for motives of publishers.

Answer (score 6):

Es simplemente que estás intentando entender algo que no está en las definiciones.  Vamos a mirar las dos con cuidado.

- **dios**: aquí, la primera acepción es la que se escribe con mayúscula, es decir, no *dios* sino *Dios*.  Lo define como *ser supremo* y *hacedor del universo*, pero hay que tener cuidado.  Dice que así es la definición con respecto a las religiones monoteístas (es decir, no se usaría con respecto a religiones no monoteístas) y además dice «es considerado» (implícitamente por los fieles de dichas religiones), sin entrar en la veracidad o no de la creencia.  La segunda también tiene lenguaje parecido, indicando que es un ser *dentro de* algún sistema de creencias, sin dictar su existencia verdadera.
- **extraterrestre**: planteas duda sobre la segunda, habiendo saltado la primera que contiene una definición muy concreta y literal.  Si algo viene de fuera de la Tierra, es, por definición, *extraterrestre*.  La segunda acepción no es muy diferente de la primera, excepto que reconoce que hay usos menos literales o cuestionablemente literal aparte de las obviamente figurativas.  Y, ya que todavía no hemos encontrado ningún ser extraterrestre, queda como algo supuesto, teorizado, literario, pero no pertenece a nuestro conocimiento científico actual.  Por tanto, queda como un unicornio que se define como un ser fabuloso, o un agujero negro, con una definición científica pero reconociendo que es «según la teoría de la relatividad» (nada diferente de la definición de Dios) porque no hay ninguna palabra final sobre los agujeros negros.  Puedes comparar la definición del agujero negro con la del agujero de ozono, que se define como «Región de la atmósfera en la que se produce una disminución de la concentración de ozono, más pronunciada en la Antártida» sin tener que especificar un marco teórico o teológico porque forma parte del conocimiento científico actual y es algo bien observado y probado.

Comment: @AlbertoMartin claro que existen meteoritos. Y si los llamamos extraterrestres, usamos la primera acepción al denominarlos así. La definición de Dios es *ser supremo* que lo es, sea que exista o no. Mercurio es un dios. No creo que nadie hoy en día le piensa dios verdadero, pero sigue siendo, por definición, un dios, y su definición debería ser *dios/deidad que en la religión romana antigua es considerado/a el mensajero de los dioses*

Comment: En realidad en la definición de Dios no dice que sea ésa la definición con respecto a las religiones monoteístas como apuntas, sino que en las religiones monoteístas se le considera hacedor del Universo. Su existencia se asume. Es un matiz muy importante. Para que dijese lo que tú interpretas, debería ser: "En las religiones monoteístas, ser supremo que...", pero no es lo que dice.

Comment: Disculpa @guifa, estaba editando la respuesta nada más ponerla y me has respondido justo entonces. Dejo constancia de que antes de editarla había preguntando retóricamente si no existían los meteoritos.

Comment: Como bien apuntas en tu respuesta, en la definición de unicornio, la RAE deja bien claro que es un animal fabuloso, una fantasía si se quiere. Entonces, ¿Por qué el trato distinto? ¿Por qué no aplicar la misma fórmula?

Comment: Cabe notar la primera definición de Dios en el diccionario de autoridades para contrastar con la actual: *nombre Sagrado del primer y supremo Ente necessario, eterno y infinito, cuyo Ser como no se puede comprehender no se puede definir, y solo se puede sacar de sus Sagrados Oráculos, que es el que es princípio y fin de todas las cosas: que crió el Universo por su Poder, que le conserva [iii.286] por su Bondad, que le rige por su Providéncia, que todo pende de su voluntad, y procede de su magnificencia infinita.*

Comment: Muy interesante. No sabía que la RAE se pronunciase tan contundentemente sobre la religión. No deja de saberme mal y parecerme innecesario despreciar a las posibles futuras bacterias "que nos caigan encima" con el "supuestamente", pero esta información me parece más que suficiente como para dar por respondida la pregunta (Tampoco conocía el diccionario de autoridades, otro aporte interesante). ¿Podrías por favor añadirla a tu respuesta para darla por (más que) aceptable?

Comment: Sí buena respuesta guifa. Añadir la definición del diccionario de autoridades sería genial para completarla. @AlbertoMartín Estoy en parte de acuerdo con vos, aunque hay que pensar que la RAE intenta definir más un concepto que una entidad existente. Es como ver el vaso medio lleno o medio vacío.